# jQuery hasClass doesn't work looping through children

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to look for certain elements if they contain a certain class in a Wordpress Widget. But what I can't understand is why the `authors.hasClass()` is OK, but the `currentAuthor.hasClass()` throws an error saying it's not a function!

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
var authors = jQuery("li");
authors.hasClass("active");

for (i = 0; i < authors.length; i++) { 
    var currentAuthor = authors[i];
    currentAuthor.hasClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By looping through the objects as an array, youre looking at them as standard JavaScript objects. Because `hasClass()` is a jQuery method, it can only be used on jQuery objects. You can use jQuery's `.each()` instead, where `jQuery(this)` refers to the current element in the loop.

```
var authors = jQuery("li");

authors.each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("active")){
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

That being said, why select all the `li` elements and then check if they have the active class, when you can simply just select all active elements?

```
var $active = jQuery("li.active");

$active.each(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Or depending on what you're doing, you may not even need `each()`

```
// Turn all active li elements red
var $active = jQuery("li.active");
$active.css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Beacuse `authors[i]` returns not jQuery object but raw DOM element (so it doesn't have jQuery methods like `hasClass`).
According to jQuery docs:

> A jQuery object is an array-like wrapper around one or more DOM
>   elements. To get a reference to the actual DOM elements (instead of
>   the jQuery object), you have two options. The first (and fastest)
>   method is to use array notation...

To solve your problem you have to wrap returned element in jQuery object like this:

`var currentAuthor = $(authors[i]);`

or use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method to get jQuery object from collection:

`var currentAuthor = authors.eq(i);`